# Find $a+b$ given $f(f(x)) = x$ where $f$ is piecewise defined

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

For some constants $a$ and $b,$ let $$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
9 - 2x & \text{if } x \le 3, \\
ax + b & \text{if } x > 3.
\end{array}
\right.$$The function $f$ has the property that $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x.$ What is $a + b?$

At first, I thought of plugging $x=1,$ to get $a+b,$ but that wouldn't be much of a help, as $1<3.$ Solution?

Comment: Where is this from? Since you're given a property about $f(f(x))$, might be a good idea to compute this object

Comment: @CalvinKhor How would he know if $f(x)$ larger than $3$ or not? ;)

Comment: @CSchofx well, the OP would have gotten somewhere if he tried to compute it, because you *can* for $x\le 3$. And this is what your answer does. The issue of the OP is that they didnt push through.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a$ and $b$ exist such that they satisfy the given conditions.
For $x = 0$, we get $f(x) = 9$.

It is given that, $f(f(x)) = x$

$$\therefore 9a + b = 0$$

Simillarly using $x = 1$, and $f(f(x)) = x$ we get,

$$7a + b = 1$$

Solving these two equations gives:

$$a = \frac{-1}{2}, b = \frac{9}{2}$$

Now let's show that with these values for $a$ and $b$ $f(f(x)) = x$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Case I:** $x < 3$

It is obvious that $x < 3 \implies f(x) > 3$.

Therefore, $f(f(x)) = f(9-2x) = \frac{-1}{2}(9-2x) + \frac{9}{2} = x$

**Case II:** $x = 3$

$x = 3 \implies f(x) = 3 \implies f(f(x)) = 3 = x$

**Case II:** $x > 3$

Again it is obvious that $x > 3 \implies f(x) < 3$.

Therefore, $f(f(x)) = f(ax + b) = 9 - 2 (\frac{-1}{2}x + \frac{9}{2}) = x$

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute two values that are less than $3$. Why? because this is what will output a number - and you will know if it is greater or less than $3$.

Let's choose $x=1$ and $x=2$ for example:

$$f(f(1)) = f(7) = 7a+b = 1$$

$$f(f(2)) = f(5) = 5a+b = 2$$

Now we have a system of equations (2 eq. and 2 unknowns)
This should be straight forward from here:

$$ a = - \frac{1}{2}$$
$$ b = \frac{9}{2}$$

And thus: $$a + b = \frac{8}{2} = 4$$

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another simple solution
$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
9 - 2x & \text{if } x \le 3 \\
ax + b & \text{if } x > 3.
\end{array}
\right.$$
$$f^{-1}(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\frac{9 - x}{2} & \text{if } x \ge 3 \\
\frac{x-b}{a} & \text{if } x < 3.
\end{array}
\right.$$

---

$f(f(x))=x \implies f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

---

Now
$$\boxed{\frac{9 - x}{2}=ax+b},x>3$$
or
$$\boxed{\frac{x-b}{a}=9-2x},x<3$$

---

Now get two equations and with any 2 values of $x$ in respective domains to obtain 2 equations giving $a,b$

**Example**

Take $x=4$
$$4a+b=\frac{5}{2}$$
Take $x=1$
$$7a+b=1$$

Solve to get $\boxed{a=\frac{-1}{2}}$ and $\boxed{b=\frac{9}{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

As $(0,9)$ and $(4.5,0)$ are points of $9-2x$ we notice that $(9,0)$ and $(0,4.5)$ are two points on $ax+b$. From here $ax+b=-0.5x+4.5$.